# Access mysql server remotely from another network

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL wamp server running on my laptop. I created a php file to run a SQL query on the database and return some rows. When I run the php file on a browser in my laptop with the URL

```
http://192.168.2.10/getData.php?sender=x
```

I get the result. I can get the same result with the same URL on a browser of my mobile phone connected to the same network. But, I cant get the result when I use mobile data instead of the network used by the laptop.

I studied about it and found out I have to use

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON chats.* TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'
```

which I did. Then, on the mobile phone I figured I have to use some combination of global and local IP of the server. But what combination should I use?

Answer (score 0):

When your using php, the connection made needs to be "seen" from the server which **executes** the .php script (that can be different ip then your mysql server). In that case you need to make sure the user used has either user@% where % means allow form any ip, or user@ip where ip is the ip connecting from.

On your mobile phone you enter the ip of the webserver + the path to the .php script. In your case that seems to be `http://192.168.2.10/getData.php?sender=x`

Now you need to make sure that the webserver is bound to your external ip adress (and not localhost) in that case you the url will not work. To be sure all works, take another pc/laptop (in the same network) and check if you run the script from  the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Logically if your phone is connected to mobile + LAN, you should able to access the link (http://192.168.2.10/getData.php?sender=x) without grant anything to mysql user, since the getData.php is using "localhost" to connect to mysql, correct me if i'm wrong.

If your requirement is : Laptop (LAN) and Phone (on mobile data), and you want to use your mobile to access the laptop url, then you will need external IP of your LAN connection and proper port 80 forwarding to your laptop IP from router/modem. After that, you should able to access to your laptop using the http://**LAN'sExternalIP**/getData.php?sender=x using your phone. If your LAN connection is without internet connection. Then it is not possible to access it from phone (mobile data).

Other than that, you will also need to do some setting to your wamp's apache configuration, which you can refer [here](http://www.simonewebdesign.it/how-to-put-online-your-wampserver/). And also need to Put the wamp to online by right click its icon near taskbar.
[image]

Comment: This looks like it should work, but strangely doesn't for me! I moved my wamp server from port 80 to 8080. I did port forwarding by adding two 2 seperate entries for TCP and UDP through port 8080. (Inbound port - 8080, private port - 8080). Then I put the wamp server to be publicly available by editing the httpd.conf file by changing the ServerName to "local ip:80" and "require all granted" and "allow from all". Now I should be able to access by "globalip:8080" but still cant.

Comment: I used "http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/" to check if my port is open. It shows that Port 80 is closed on my global ip. I dont know where's the problem.

Comment: check the firewall where the wamp is installed. make sure the port is allowed.